# Trying to run su with shell_exec on PHP-FPM and nginx

Tags: nginx, php

So, i've been trying to run the following command `su - username -c whoami` with shell_exec(), but the only thing i get back is a NULL. When running in PHP interactive mode, logged as the `nginx` user, or running through Apache, i get the correct output. Everything works perfectly. Here's my code:

`var_dump(shell_exec('su - username -c whoami'));`

I suspect it's something related to PHP-FPM. Any ideas, guys?